# How to get the first node that has no parent from a node in a self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using MySQL / MariaDB database. I can't use the procedure because I don't have the right and I want to select the top parent that have not upper parent from one of the child.

Examples :

`Familly > CMP > ACC`

I select the ACC child and I want the top parent that is Familly in this case.

.

`Familly > CMP > Numeric > CFRA`

I select the CFRA child and I want the top parent that is Familly in this case.

Here is my table :

```sql
create table llx_categorie
(
    rowid       int auto_increment primary key,
    entity      int     default 1 not null,
    fk_parent   int     default 0 not null,
    label       varchar(255)      not null,
    type        tinyint default 1 not null,
    description text              null,
);
```

Here is what I want to see :

```
child_label    top_parrent_label
ACC            Familly
```

and that is what I have try :

```sql
  SELECT rowid, label
  FROM llx_categorie m
  WHERE rowid=170
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.rowid, m.label
  FROM llx_categorie m
  INNER JOIN llx_categorie p
    ON p.rowid = m.fk_parent
```

But that return every brother node.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all child records connected to any parent record from a self join. Use a where clause to limit down the results from the self join for one side to only be parents:

```
SELECT c.*, parent.*
FROM llx_categorie c
INNER JOIN llx_categorie parent on c.fk_parent = parent.rowid
WHERE parent.fk_parent is null
```

For your instance, you will need to change the condition to equal 0 instead of null because your column is not null. I am not stating that in the SQL above because any visitors referencing this article should not connect to a 0 record by default. That schema paradigm is strongly not recommended. The foreign key constraint will try and enforce that 0 value within your foreign key. This can make the self join less performant, it could result in foreign key errors when a 0-record doesn't exist, and it will confuse new devs that would expect a null for a foreign key that doesn't have an associated row.

Comment: Family CMP and ACC is not a different table than in the same table: llx_categorie. ACC have on fk_parrent the rowid of CMP cmp have on fk_parrent the rowid of Family. And my problem is I want to join the table itself while the fk_parrent key is not null

Comment: i've made an additional suggestion but still the goal is vague. the schema does not allow you to have records that have no parent.

Comment: The rowid is my primary key so that can't be null, but yes the fk_parrent can be null. And when it's null that mean it's the first node element. This request (modification of yours) :

`SELECT c.label, parent.label
FROM llx_categorie c
LEFT JOIN llx_categorie parent on c.fk_parent = parent.rowid
WHERE parent.fk_parent = 0
`
Works but I have only one of the childs node of parrent node

Comment: you state that fk_parrent cannot be null: 
" fk_parent   int     default 0 not null,"

Comment: yes, but it's the idea when it's at 0 it's like they have no upper parent

Comment: Thats bad. Don't do that. the foreign key will still enforce the 0 records so a llx_categorie with rowid 0 still has to exist.

Comment: It's not my schema it comes from Dolibarr ERP but I need to deal with it. I think that sort of thing was handle by PHP when there is an insertion. But it's not what I want to do.